# React state with arrays of objects: is it ok to leave some objects unchanged?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component with a state containing a list of objects, each with another list of objects inside of it. Something like:

```
this.state = {
  posts: [
    { id, comments: [{...}, {...}] }, 
    { id, comments: [{...}, {...}] }
  ]
}
```

If I need to add a new comment to a specific post, then in order to keep the state immutable, as far as I understand, I must:

1. Make a shallow copy of `posts`;
2. Find the post with the right `id`, and make a shallow copy of it;
3. Make a shallow copy of the post's `comments`;
4. Add the new comment.

The question is: is all that really necessary? Wouldn't a shallow copy of `posts` be enough to signal to React that it has changed? Also, can I leave all the rest of the posts (and comments) unchanged, or do I need to basically clone everything?

Below is my solution so far. Notice that unchanged posts are entirely ignored.

```
handleNewComment(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
    // shallow copy of posts
    posts: this.state.posts.map(p => {
      if (p.id == e.target.postId.value) {
        // shallow copy of modified post
        return {
          ...p,
          // shallow copy of comments
          comments: p.comments.concat({
            author: e.target.author.value,
            content: e.target.content.value
          })
        }
      } else {
        // unchanged elements stay the same
        return p;
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: When you use a .map function you return a new array so you don't need to create a shallow copy of the comments.

Comment: @zamarrowski, but the `.map` copy is a shallow copy, so the objects/arrays inside of the `posts` array stay the same. Is it enough to simply make a shallow copy of `posts`? That's basically my question.